# Templating engine for node.js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm using node js for my website project,
now I don't know for template which one is better handlebars or embeddedejs
thanks for any help

Comment: General "A or B" questions aren't [on-topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) as their answers tend to be mostly opinion. Though, in this case, I would suggest Handlebars only because [`ejs`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ejs) isn't currently being maintained ("*last updated 7 months ago*").

Answer (score 2):

It might depend largely, depending on your timeframe for learning the system, on what kind of framework you're more used to using, if you have used a templating system before. Otherwise, it might depend on your language of proficiency. For example, if you've done a lot of work in PHP, you'll find EJS very easy to pick up, because the structure is very similar. For example

In EJS:

```
<% 
    // Write code here 
%>
```

Or to print a variable:

```
<%= variable %>
```

This is very similar to PHP:

```
<?php 
    // Write code here 
?>

<?= $variableToPrint ?>
```

However, if you've used a templating system such as Django before, then you'll find handlebars easier to work with, because it's quite similar to that.

However, easy of learning shouldn't be your only concern. If you have the time to learn a new templating system, then you can peruse the advice given as answers here, and find the best one for the long term.